# Why is this function in $L^1$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-operators

I had a question about a claim made in the paper "Group Invariant Scattering" and why it is true. Consider the function $h_j(x) = 2^{nj}\psi(2^jx)$, where $\psi$ is a function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi dx = 0$ and all its first and second partial derivatives have decay of the form $O((1+|x|)^{-n-3})$. Does the function $\theta(x) = \sum_{j \leq 0} h_j \ast h_j(x)$ satisfy $\theta \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

The justification for this in the paper is the following: since $\hat{\theta}(\omega) = \sum_{j \leq 0}  |\hat{h}(2^{-j} \omega)|$ and $\hat{h}(0) = 0$ and $h$ is both regular with a polynomial decay, we verify that $\|\theta\|_1 < \infty.$ Why exactly does $\theta$ having zero average and $h$ being both regular with a polynomial decay yield the desired result? Is there some theorem that was applied here?

Note: if I try to bound by taking the absolute value sign inside of the sum (without doing anything else), the integral diverges because of the sum over $j$, so I don't think this would be the reason.

Comment: What is the full reference to the paper and where exactly is the claim in question?

Comment: Here is the axriv link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.2286.pdf. The claim is at the bottom of pg 66.